# Scenekit Grouped Animations

Tags: ios, animation, scenekit

I am trying to extract animations from one DAE file that contains a few animations. I want to break up the animation in groups so I can play specific animations in the timeline.

I am using the "skinning" slide from the WWDC as a reference, but it is all in objective-c and I think something has been lost in translation when trying to do this in swift.

I have my character loaded in the scene but when i run this code the animation does not run. Whats going on?

```
 for animationID in animationsIDs {
            if let animation = sceneSource.entryWithIdentifier(animationID, withClass: CAAnimation.self) as? CAAnimation {
                var maxDuration = max(maxDuration, animation.duration);
                longAnimations.append(animation)
            }

        let longAnimationsGroup = CAAnimationGroup()
        longAnimationsGroup.animations = longAnimations
        longAnimationsGroup.duration = maxDuration


        let idleAnimationGroup :CAAnimationGroup = longAnimationsGroup.copy() as CAAnimationGroup
        idleAnimationGroup.timeOffset = 0.0
      _idleAnimationGroup.animations = [idleAnimationGroup]
        _idleAnimationGroup.duration = 1.0
        _idleAnimationGroup.repeatCount = FLT_MAX
        _idleAnimationGroup.autoreverses = true


        SCNTransaction.begin()

        self._character.addAnimation(_idleAnimationGroup, forKey: "animation")

        SCNTransaction.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. it seems that your `for` loop is missing a closing bracket. Currently you are adding (and thus overriding) an animation with the key `"animation"` for each `animationID`
2. how and where is `_idleAnimationGroup` created?